# How to run jpql queries in a console in Spring Data project?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql, projection, dto

I'm new to Spring Data and trying to learn to projections and DTOs.
If you run a plain Hibernate or JPA project in Idea, there is an access to jpql tool window like View -> Tool Windows -> Persistence.
But when open a Spring Data project in idea the feature is unavailable.

Could i run and debug hql|jpql queries for my DTOs in Idea for Spring Data?
Which is the best tool to debug|run complex jpql queries like joins etc.?
Should i consider another ide or a tool?
Where is a good source of working examples for projections and jpql?

Comment: **What** you would like to debug? If your objective is see the generated SQL, you can enable the `show-sql` option on the spring jpa properties